# Check specifically if jQuery.ui.autocomplete is undefined

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to use `jQuery UI` in a modulated way. Instead of loading one `.JS` file (bigger than 200kb) with all `jQuery UI` funcionality:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.custom.js"></script>
```

I intent to load only needed ones (for autocomplete, for instance):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.menu.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

But i want to load these files through javascript only if autocomplete functionality isn't detected. I know I can check if `jQuery UI` is loaded to a page with this `JavaScript` condition:

```
if (typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined'){
    // jQuery UI core is loaded
}
```

What I need to do is check specifically if `jQuery UI` Autocomplete functionality is available to use:

```
if (typeof jQuery.ui.autocomplete !== 'undefined'){
    // jQuery UI autocomplete is loaded
}
```

But the code above returns this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a way of load `jQuery UI` libraries only when one of its resources are used. Hotlink from websites such as Google isn't an option, and I can't put all `jQuery UI` libraries on all pages of a website I'm working with. To achieve this, I'll make custom javascript functions for using `jQuery UI` Widgets such as Autocomplete and Datepicker, and inside these functions, I'll check if `jQuery UI` libraries are loaded, and load them if they aren't. I've achieved that for Autocomplete and Datepicker, but they won't work if run both functions on a same page, because my `jQuery UI` libraries check isn't totally functional.

Anyone know some way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't autocomplete defined as part of a jquery extension?  I'd think you should be checking:

```
$.fn.autocomplete
```

Since you call $('element').autocomplete(); to call the plugin.

Comment: Tried that solution a week ago and that's the best way of solving this problem. I just needed to test if jQuery UI Core library is loaded, and then test all of them. Something like this:

if($.ui != undefined && $.ui.autocomplete != undefined){ return true; }

Of course I needed to check all needed js libraries, so I made a function that check all libraries that I need to load, then start loading it with a recursive function that loads all js files through $.ajax (or $.getScript without cache).